# how to import pre writen HTML code into TKinter

Tags: python, html, tkinter

i have done research on running HTML code in python, i have the libraries imported just i have my code in a HTML file. So is there any way to import it into python?

Thanks Mrcottonball.

I have tried this code ↓↓↓

The problem is i need to use HTML outside of python and occasionally import it as a .html file

`

```
# Import Module
from tkinter import *
from tkhtmlview import HTMLLabel
 
# Create Object
root = Tk()
 
# Set Geometry
root.geometry("400x400")
 
# Add label
my_label = HTMLLabel(root, html="""
        <h1>HI</h1>
        <h2>HI</h2>
        <h3>HI</h3>
        <h4>HI</h4>
        <h5>HI</h5>
        <h6>HI</h6>
    """)
 
# Adjust label
my_label.pack(pady=20, padx=20)
 
# Execute Tkinter
root.mainloop()
```

`

any help would be appreciated

kind regards, Mrcottonball :)

Comment: just open the file and read it's contents.

Comment: Do you have an HTML file outside of Python and you want to display it on the tkinter window? Just use `file.open('<path to HTML file>')`